# Using Python "Mixer" library with SQL Alchemy models with constructor arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Mixer as a fixture generator for SQLAlchemy models with flask as a mixer backend. I have an User model with a constructor:

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    salt = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        # Stuff to init
        pass
```

Following Mixer's documentation I created a Mixer subclass with an overridden method to populate the model with constructor parameters as follows:

```
class MixerForModelsWithConstructor(Mixer):
    """
    Mixer for models which requires constructor values
    """
    def populate_target(self, values):
        target = self.__scheme(**values)
        return target
```

This is how I create a mixer fixture:

```
mixer = mixer = MixerForModelsWithConstructor(app=app)
user = mixer.blend(Users, username='test', password='test')
```

Where `app` is the Flask App object. 
But, when I run the tests, all the involved tasks fails because the model constructor still expects the parameters and Mixer is not passing them.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the documentation is outdated.

Here is the proper code to use:

```
class CustomTypeMixer(TypeMixer):
    def __init__(self, cls, mixer=None, factory=None, fake=True):
        super().__init__(cls, mixer=mixer, factory=factory, fake=fake)
        self.__scheme = cls  # not sure why above line isn't setting this... is this the keyword 'cls' or just a variable named 'cls'?

    def populate_target(self, values):
        """ Populate a target by values. """
        target = self.__scheme(**dict(values))
        return target


class CustomMixer(Mixer):
    type_mixer_cls = CustomTypeMixer


mixer = CustomMixer(session=session, commit=True)
```

Copied from this answer https://github.com/klen/mixer/issues/12#issuecomment-409954829